# Is Google GCM still available?

Tags: android, cordova, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to create a simple android push notification app using Phonegap build and GCM.. I currently can get the android's device token using a phonegap plugin and store it in my database without any issue.

I just need to know if I can still use GCM (Google cloud messaging) OR I need to start using FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging)?

Any tutorial I found on Google is about GCM and they all say to enable the 'Auth & API' under the google cloud messaging section in the google console. but when i go to GCM in my Google console, I don't see anything like that and everything seems to be about FCM which is frustrating when there are no information about how to use it with Phonegap build!

Is Google GCM still available or the new app 'Have' to start using FCM from now on?

I mean Google console is confusing enough without them keep changing everything every month or so!!

Could someone please advise on this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloud Messaging (GCM) is now part of Firebase, see also [this link](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/faq).

Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) is the new version of GCM. It inherits the reliable and scalable GCM infrastructure, plus new features!

> If you are integrating messaging in a new app, start with FCM. GCM users are strongly recommended to upgrade to FCM, in order to benefit from new FCM features today and in the future.

Is GCM going to be deprecated?

> We will continue to support the current version of GCM Android and iOS SDKs because we know a lot of developers are using GCM SDKs today to handle notifications, and client app upgrade takes time.
>
> But all new client-side features will be added to FCM SDKs only moving forward. You are strongly encouraged to upgrade to FCM SDKs.

In short, stop using Google developer console in order to use GCM, use this:
https://console.firebase.google.com/?pli=1, as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I saw all that information in the Firebase account and when i clicked on the GCM link in my google console... but that still doesn't answer my question! Firebase usage is totally different than GCM usage thus causing the confusion and making all the tutorials about GCM on Google obsolete.

Comment: Stop using GCM via google developer console, see the updated answer.